# com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance not found in Google App Engine project

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, google-eclipse-plugin

I installed the Google Plugin for Eclipse and created a new Google App Engine project just as decribed in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse. When building the project I'm getting the error 
Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance

I have searched similar questions on stackoverflow and the only suggestions were to use JDK 7 and uninstall any existing JDK 6 even if not pointed in Eclipse Installed Jres. I have done both, and I'm still I'm facing the same error. This is on Windows 7 x64 machine and the Eclipse and JDK are 32 bit ones. I also tried on another computer which is a Windows server 2008 x64 machine and again the Eclipse and JDK 32 bit. I face the same error there also.

Please help before I shoot myself.

Comment: So this is not due to the project setting because it is trying to run some main method during the build step and it is failing to load the Enhance class. I hear that this is some enhancement step during the build but why doesn't it set any required classpath for such a step?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using JDO/JPA, uncheck the box for this option in the App Engine tab for your project.

If you do use them, make sure that the relevant files are present in the WEB-INF/lib/ folder: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview?csw=1

Comment: I unchecked the "Use Datanucleus JDO/JPA to access the datasotre" and still get the same error. Apparantly the error I get is from a so-called "Enhancement" step during the build. Why doesn't it set the proper classpath required for the enhancement?

Comment: Where do you see this error - production or development?

Comment: On development. I have installed the google plugin on another machine and face the same error there also.

Comment: In case its not clear I'm facing the problem during building the project, not running.

Comment: Do you see any warnings in the Problems tab?

Comment: No warnings displayed.